Undetectable emulator that passes SafetyNet/Play Integrity
Most emulators are easily detectable and can't pass SafetyNet/Play Integrity. Are there any low-level emulators that are not distinguishable from a real device and run a full Android? It should be not just a virtualization but a full ARM emulator that fakes everything a real device would have. It should run on Windows.

Related post on XDA //Searching that thread might help

The simple answer is: Impossible. Even rooted hardware devices are not capable to fake the MEETS_STRONG_INTEGRITY level. Why do you think an emulator could do that?

@Robert if emulator behaves exactly like real devices and doesn't have root, why no?

Because physical phones have a hardware security element (or a TTE part in the main CPU) containing cryptographic key material that is required to pass the test. Emulators don't have a hardware security element and even if you would get one and place it in your PC it would miss the key material by Google that is used in the Play Integrity test.

@Robert not every model has a hardware security in it and if it contains a key, it's very possible that someone will be able to reverse-engineer their device and extract it

Hardware security is mandatory for recent Android devices and it is the only way to pass STRONG_INTEGRITY / high integrity see  https://support.cortado.com/en/support/solutions/articles/43000590090-how-to-set-a-minimum-integrity-level-for-android-devices

Possible dupe, not answered yet (or possibly unsolvable): How to run an Android application requiring the SafetyNet/basic root check on a PC?

I don't think there is any publicly available. It's entirely possible, but very difficult. You could spoof an older device that doesn't have the hardware security module, also use a bootloader spoofer (+Magisk + LSPosed) to make it look like the bootloader is locked, and use an ARM host like a Raspberry Pi 5 or an Azure arm64 VM.
